# Symfony - Installing assetic

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I have used composer to install bootstrap css and jquery to the vendor directory and I am trying to install assetic using the following page for guidance:

[Symfony Assetic Guidance](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#installing-and-enabling-assetic)

I have done the first part of the instruction using composer and assetic and kris wallsmith are installed in the vendor directory but when I try to edit the AppKernel file to do the next step and register assetic it complains it cannot find the class:

```
The type Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle cannot be resolved

new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
```

I am very new to php and symfony but decided I would rewrite a spring site in it but I am not getting very far... as the instructions are so simple I cannot really see what could be causing the problem.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Symfony do you use?

On Symfony 3 this works perfectly, if you are using < Symfony 3 you dont have to install AsseticBundle via composer manually, it is in basic symfony bundles.

https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Comment: my require statement is: "symfony/symfony" : "3.0.*",